# Is there a Java Executable Wrapper that reads the classpaths and JavaFX modules from a configuration file?

Tags: java, javafx, executable-jar, launch4j, jsmooth

I'm trying to launch my java program from an executable file that passes all the required parameters like the classpath and the JavaFX modules.
I've successfully created executables with tools like Launch4j and JSmooth. The problem is, when the java program updates itself and requires new JavaFX modules, the executable will no longer work. Is there a way that my executable can read those parameters (or any parameters) from a configuration file, so that my program can update that configuration file if needed (similar to how Launch4j can read .l4j.ini files containing JVM parameters) ? Or is there an Executable Wrapper that supports this?

Comment: @user:5772697 May I ask you why you need to change exe configuration sinse you also can update your executables? In any case take a look at the tool https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin. It is flexible and I guess it has options you need.